# run locally Step Function defined in a SAM template

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I follow the guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-lambda.html to run locally a Step Function defined inline.

But I don't found any guide how to test locally a Step Function defined into a SAM template (template.yaml).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Currently Step Functions integration with SAM is still at an early phase. It offers following functionalities from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-sam-sfn.html):

> Get started in minutes using a AWS SAM sample template.
>
> Build your state machine into your serverless application.
>
> Use variable substitution to substitute ARNs into your state machine
> at time of deployment.
>
> Simplify specifying your state machine role using AWS SAM policy
> templates.
>
> Trigger state machine executions with API Gateway, EventBridge events,
> or on a schedule within your AWS SAM template.

However, unlike you can use SAM local to emulate Lambda and API Gateway locally, you cannot emulate Step Functions locally using SAM.

[Step Functions Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local.html) is the only officially  supported way to test your state machines locally, pairing with SAM local command, you can use the local version of Step Functions invoking a local version of AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SDK for the desired language and create your automated tests by following the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html.

Node.js example:

```js
const stepfunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions({endpoint: 'http://localhost:8083'});
```

Other option is use AWS CLI with bash/sh files and creating manual (strange) tests that it can be invoked by "npm run", like: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-lambda.html.

```sh
$ aws stepfunctions --endpoint http://localhost:8083 <command>
```